# How to synchronize The Loop with the max post per page?

Tags: loop

I know I can use get_posts() and then specify to only get a certain number of posts, but I don't know how to use the value that the site admin has set in his settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the setting for posts per page set under `Settings > Reading` via [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option):

```
$posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
```

Comment: So that's how everyone does it? They use this in The Loop?

Comment: maybe you should edit your question and explain in better detail what you're trying to do. "the loop" outputs the results of a query. the default query for each page is generated automatically, so query parameters like posts per page don't need to be specified. if you're creating a query *in addition to* the default query, you can just omit the posts per page parameter and it will default to whatever is set in that option.